# For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $A_n=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{N}^3: x<y, y<z, z\leq n+1\}$ count the number of elements in $A_n$

Tags: combinatorics

> For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $A_n=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{N}^3: x<y, y<z, z\leq n+1\}$ count the number of elements in $A_n$

I computed the number for $n=0,1,2$

For $n=0:$

$(0,0,1)$

$1$ elements

For $n=1$:

$(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(1,1,2),(1,0,2),0,1,2)$

$5$ elements

For $n=2$:

All from $n=1$ and $(0,1,3),(1,0,3),(1,1,3),(2,2,3),(2,1,3),(1,2,3),(2,2,3),(0,2,3)$

$13$ elements

So I can see that I will have $4^2$ combinations where $z=4$ and $n=3$ plus all the previous ones.

So I have $(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2+(n-3)^2+...+(1)^2$ solutions for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Which gives $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i)^2$

I'm not sure how to justify this though, it looks similar to binomial theorem, but I have a square.

Comment: For base cases are wrong. $A_0 = \emptyset$ since it is impossible to pick three naturals $x < y < z < 1$. Similarly, $A_1 = \{(0,1,2 )\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original post we're asked how many elements are in

$$\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{N}^3\,\vert\,x<y<z\le n+1\}.$$

Also, I'm going to infer from the original post that $\Bbb{N}$ denotes the set of non-negative integers. Some mathematicians define $\Bbb{N}$ this way, while others define $\Bbb{N}$ to be the positive integers. Since the original post had $\Bbb{N}$ being the non-negatives, let's stick with that.

Note that the set $\{0,1,\ldots,n+1\}$ has $n+2$ elements.

It follows that $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{N}^3\,\vert\,x<y<z\le n+1\}$ has $\binom{n+2}{3}$ elements.

As user Brian noted in a comment, the cases where $n=0$, $n=1$, $n=2$, where not calculated correctly, since not all of the triples $(x,y,z)$ satisfied $x<y<z\le n+1$.

For $n=0$, we should have $\binom{2}{3}=0$ triples.

For $n=1$, we should have $\binom{3}{3}=1$ triple, namely $(0,1,2)$.

For $n=2$, we should have $\binom{4}{3}=4$ triples, namely $(0,1,2)$, $(0,1,3)$, $(0,2,3)$, and $(1,2,3)$.

Comment: So I understand that there are $n+2$ elements, but do you not have to account for the order of the elements? Just having ${n+2 \choose 3}$ makes it seem like you can have $(3,1,0)$ or does it not matter since this would overlap with $(0,1,3)$?

Comment: Since each triple $(x,y,z)$ must satisfy $x<y<z$, whenever we pick $3$ elements from $\{0,1,\ldots,n+1\}$ there is exactly one way to turn those $3$ elements into a triple. Just let $x$ be the smallest; let $z$ be the largest; and let $y$ be the one in the middle.